# tcsh foreach one liner only shows first object

Tags: bash, foreach, tcsh

I know how to use the foreach as a shell script. But I encountered a wired problem let's say I'm trying to just print folder names, I can do:

```
foreach f (*/)
  echo $f
  end
```

and the output will be 1/, 2/, 3/
But let's say I'm trying to do this as a one-liner:

```
foreach f (*/) ; echo $f ; end
```

first of all, it will not finish and it would make me enter another 'end' to finish the foreach, and after I do, it will only show the first element and not go through all the folders like before.

does someone knows why this is happening and what can I do so it will work properly?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From man tcsh

```
The foreach, switch, and while statements, as  well  as 
the if-then-else form of the if statement, require that 
the major keywords appear in a  single  simple  command 
on an input line as shown below.
```